# DRY less code share between siblings

Tags: html, css, less

Consider the following DOM:

```
<div class="first">
    <div class="nested"></div>
</div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

In LESS I have:

```
.first {
    margin: 19px;

    .nested{ color: white; }
 }
```

I want to apply `margin: 19px` to `.second` as well.

This applies, if the `.second` div is nested inside `.first`:

```
.first {
    &, .second {
        margin: 19px;
    }

    .nested{ color: white; }
 }
```

Is it possible to do it inside `.first` block, so it applies on `.second` in the above markup structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And why do you want to put `.second` inside `.first`?

Here're three variants:

**1.** "Never use nesting for the sake of nesting":

```
.first, .second {
    margin: 19px;
}

.first .nested {
    color: white;
}
```

**2.** "I still want nesting and I don't care if result contains redundant selectors":

```
.first, .second {
    margin: 19px;

    .nested {
        color: white;
    }
}
```

**3.** "I don't like **1** or **2** and I don't care if my code is not quite readable":

```
.first {
    margin: 19px;

    .nested {
        color: white;
    }
}

.second:extend(.first) {}
```

**---**

P.S. Actually, thinking of it more, personally I would use the **4**th variant:

HTML:

```
<div class="first">
    <div class="unique-class-name"></div>
</div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Less:

```
.first, .second {
    margin: 19px;
}

.unique-class-name {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking solution like #3. :) Can you explain what can go inside curly brackets of extend and to which selector it would belong?

Comment: The curly brackets there are just styles of the `.second` (they do not relate to `extend`), you can put unique `.second` CSS properties there as usual.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was expecting. Web Essentials is rendering it incorrectly at the moment but http://less2css.org show the correct result. They must be using old LESS in current version of Web Essentials.